# Proof of gamma matrix trace identity from Griffiths Introduction to Particle Physics

Tags: momentum, dirac-matrices, trace

Griffiths states that the product of eq (9.8):

$ 8[p_1^\mu p_3^\nu + p_1^\nu p_3^\mu -g^{\mu\nu}(p_1 \cdot p_3) -i\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma}]$

and eq (9.9)

$ 8[p_{2\mu} p_{4\nu} + p_{2\nu} p_{4\mu} -g_{\mu\nu}(p_2 \cdot p_4) -i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau]$

yields (from eq (9.10))

$256(p_1 \cdot p_2)(p_3 \cdot p_4)$

When I try to compute this, I get (and it is quite tedious so bare with me):

$$64[p_1^\mu p_3^\nu (p_{2\mu} p_{4\nu} + p_{2\nu} p_{4\mu} -g_{\mu\nu}(p_2 \cdot p_4) -i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau) $$
$$+ p_1^\nu p_3^\mu (p_{2\mu} p_{4\nu} + p_{2\nu} p_{4\mu} -g_{\mu\nu}(p_2 \cdot p_4) -i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau) $$
$$-g^{\mu\nu}(p_1 \cdot p_3) (p_{2\mu} p_{4\nu} + p_{2\nu} p_{4\mu} -g_{\mu\nu}(p_2 \cdot p_4) -i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau) $$
$$-i\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma} (p_{2\mu} p_{4\nu} + p_{2\nu} p_{4\mu} -g_{\mu\nu}(p_2 \cdot p_4) -i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau)] = ...$$
$$
$$

$$...= 64[ (p_1 \cdot p_2)(p_3 \cdot p_4)+(p_1 \cdot p_4)(p_2 \cdot p_3) - (p_1 \cdot p_3)(p_2 \cdot p_4) -i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_1^\mu p_3^\nu p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau $$
$$+ (p_1 \cdot p_4)(p_2 \cdot p_3) + (p_1 \cdot p_2)(p_3 \cdot p_4) - (p_1 \cdot p_3)(p_2 \cdot p_4) - i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_1^\nu p_3^\mu p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau $$
$$- (p_1 \cdot p_3)(p_2 \cdot p_4) - (p_1 \cdot p_3)(p_2 \cdot p_4) + (p_1 \cdot p_3)(p_2 \cdot p_4) + i(p_1 \cdot p_3)g^{\mu \nu}i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau $$
$$- i\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma}p_{2\mu} p_{4\nu} - i\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma}p_{2\nu} p_{4\mu} + i(p_2 \cdot p_4)g_{\mu\nu}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma} - \varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma}]$$
$$
$$
Now, collecting terms and using $g^{\mu \nu}\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau} = g_{\mu\nu}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma} = 0$ and $\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau} = -2(\delta_\kappa^\lambda \delta_\tau^\sigma - \delta_\tau^\lambda \delta_\kappa^\sigma)$

$$
64[2(p_1 \cdot p_2)(p_3 \cdot p_4) + 2(p_1 \cdot p_4)(p_2 \cdot p_3) - 3(p_1 \cdot p_3)(p_2 \cdot p_4) - i\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\kappa\tau}(p_1^\mu p_3^\nu p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau + p_1^\nu p_3^\mu p_2^\kappa p_4^\tau) - i\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}(p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma}p_{2\mu} p_{4\nu} +p_{1\lambda}p_{3\sigma}p_{2\nu} p_{4\mu}) + 2(p_1 \cdot p_2)(p_3 \cdot p_4) - 2(p_1 \cdot p_4)(p_2 \cdot p_3)) =...
$$
Since the terms to the Levi-Civita symbols differ by the exchange of an index, the imaginary parts go to zero and so
$$
...=64[4(p_1 \cdot p_2)(p_3 \cdot p_4) - 3(p_1 \cdot p_3)(p_2 \cdot p_4)]
$$
Why am I left with  $-3(p_1 \cdot p_3)(p_2 \cdot p_4)$?

Comment: $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}=?$

Comment: Please be aware that check-my-work questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @G.Smith I am using $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = I$. I apologize if it is, I have been looking for a proof for this identity but everyone seems to skip the computation and simply state that it computes to eq (9.10). Having done this multiple times now, I feel as if there is some notational convention or such that I am missing.

Comment: It can’t be the identity matrix. Think about why. If necessary, compute it by summing the 16 terms.

Comment: @G.Smith Ah yes, sorry, I meant $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = 1$ since we contract both indices.

Comment: No, it’s not 1. That is your mistake. Do you understand that this is a sum of 16 terms? Or, thinking about it differently, the trace of a product of two $4\times 4$ matrices?

Comment: You can never get confused if you just write out the sums implied by the Einstein convention.

Comment: @G.Smith Thank you, I don't know how I haven't caught on to that before, $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = \delta_\mu^\mu$ which is the trace of the identity matrix in d=4, so $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = 4$.

Comment: Yes, and that fixes your mistake. Thinking in terms of the trace of the identity matrix is the best way. But you don’t seem willing to recognize that these tensor contractions are also just sums of products of components. There are 16 terms, and 4 of the terms are 1 and 12 are 0.

Comment: @G.Smith Thank you once again! I've been bangning my head on this for a while.  I am aware that they are sums (Einstein summation convention), its rather that I want to get used to the shorthand notation.

Answer (score 3):

As @G.Smith pointed out, the mistake lies in assuming $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = 1$ when of course it should be $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = 4$ and so the above computation indeed becomes $256(p_1 \cdot p_2)(p_3 \cdot p_4)$